# How can I send the data to server?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I need your help, I have a problem with my code, I want to post data to server but the data cannot post, so it's make me confuse, please help me.

This is my code.

```js
private String JSON_STRING;
    LocalSession session;
    PostToServer postToServer;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    String username,area,rayon;
    EditText user;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tampil_semua_pgw);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       // getJSON();
        username =getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
        user.setText(username);


        postToServer = new PostToServer();
        postToServer.delegate = this;
        postToServer.execute(konfigurasi.URL_GET_ALL,user.getText().toString().trim());

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(TampilSemuaPgw.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);

        //getJSON();
        Log.e("loc change","long: "+user.getText().toString().trim()+" ");

    }
```

And this is my PHP code.

```html
<?php 



 //Import File Koneksi Database
 require_once('koneksi.php');
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 
 //Membuat SQL Query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_p2tl_lpb where petugas='$username'";
 
 //Mendapatkan Hasil
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
 //Membuat Array Kosong 
 $result = array();
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
  
  //Memasukkan Nama dan ID kedalam Array Kosong yang telah dibuat 
  array_push($result,array(
   "idpel"=>$row['idpel'],
   "id"=>$row['id'],
   "nama"=>$row['nama']
  ));
 }
 
 //Menampilkan Array dalam Format JSON
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
 
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code runs well, but it brings up all the data while all I want is data that appears only data with the conditions I post. please help for all of them to solve my problem, because I am confused to solve this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, but you are also showing a big security problem in your php file (sql request). Just saying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli. Like example bellow:

```
//Import File Koneksi Database
require_once('koneksi.php');
$username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : null;

// ===============================================
// This params will be in file koneksi database
// ===============================================
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';
// ===============================================
// ===============================================
// ===============================================
$result = [];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM t_p2tl_lpb WHERE petugas = :username;');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = [
            'idpel' => $row['idpel'],
            'id'    => $row['id'],
            'nama'  => $row['nama']
        ];
    }
    echo json_encode([
        'result' => $result
    ]);
    unset($pdo);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```